# Grand Central Dispatch EXC_BAD_ACCESS Exception

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, ios5.1

I have an empty block which runs fine in iPhone 6.0 simulator in Xcode, however when I switch to the iPhone 5.1 simulator I get the following exception: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // I've removed all code from here and exception still occurs.
    });
```

Any ideas what causes this? The exception is thrown at the dispatch_async line. Not sure if it matters, though I am using ARC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mistake on my part, I had the iOS Deployment Target set at 6.0. I've updated it to 5.1 now and it works fine.

Comment: Wow I was stuck on this for hours. Yet your answer here saved me probably many more. Thanks!

Comment: Another victim of this.  When I made several files a library target it picked up the current SDK target as the deployment target.  Consequently half my project binary was made up with files compiled with a deployment target of 5.0 and half with 6.0.